# @see and @uses tags not showing up with phpDocumentor

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I'm using phpDocumentor 2.5.0 and the below tags do not show up in the documentation (even if done one at a time):

```
//None of these work
 * @see MyClass::someFunction()
 * @see MyClass::someFunction() that does something
 * @uses MyClass::someFunction()
 * @uses MyClass::someFunction() to do something
 * @uses MyClass
 * @uses /MyClass
 * @uses /MyClass::someFunction()
```

How do I get it to add these to the documentation?

I am not using namespaces.

I'm running phpDocumentor like this:

```
phpdoc -d /home/development/code_to_document/ -t /home/development/documentation
```

Answer (score 1):

What docblock are these lines from?  As long as it's a true docblock:

`/**
 * @see MyClass::someFunction()
 */`

and the docblock is on a documentable code element (class, method, function, etc), then I would expect the tags to appear, even if neither MyClass nor MyClass::someFunction() were found in your code project.

If your test code meets these requirements, then you may have discovered a bug.  I suggest at least trying several of the different output templates, to see if the missing tag behavior persists over all of them.

Comment: it appears to be a bug. it does notice the `@see` tags, but never prints out the class and function. so it's an empty link. But if you do this, it "works": `@see MyClass::someFunction() MyClass::someFunction() does something`. notice i have to do it twice.

Comment: This may be related to this bug -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1079#issuecomment-48431379